# "refreshing" a c# form based on a certain radioButton selection

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write a c# program that allows a user to select/configure a number of things about the program. When the program starts, a form that contains either one text box and a set of radio buttons or three text boxes and a set of radio buttons pops up. If the former occurs (only one text box), but the user selects a specific radio button from the set, I would like to re-render the form to have the other two entries as well.

I have tried to just overwrite the form with a new one, but that didn't work. I have an event handler that works when the specific button is selected, but it doesn't handle the scenario right. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can consume _OnCheckedChanged() event of the radio button.

```
protected void radioButtonID_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (radioButtonID.Checked)
  {
    textBoxID.Visible = true;
  }
  else 
  {
    textBoxID.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does Javascript have to do with WinForms?

Comment: Right! I have misread it! Will refine my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).